# soapui - print testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, soapui

I am new in SOAPUI. I'm trying to write automatic test which will check more than 300 prints (PDF) in browser. Currently I execute this manually. I enter template_id in SoapUI (e.g EUEAI000010001), then I have PrntId (eg. 132100) and at the end I generate link to the page www where can I check my print - correct or not. I'll be very grateful if someone can give me some tips/support how to begin this process with automatic test.

Template_id I have in xml file - more than 300.

Comment: you may use input file to enter your template_id (soapui pro) otherwise try to do the same within a groovy script.

Comment: Place the 300 values in an array. pick first value a[0] in a groovy script.Set a test Caseproperty to a[0].Use this value in your api <text>'${#testCase#Property1}'</text>. Now run your request 300 times with each time different values. Also save the PrntId in some file.. so at the end you will have 300 prntid